# ContextListener provider->refreshUser() is NULL

Tags: symfony, token, roles

I've forked a library and did lots of changes on it. When i did auth with steam, it is saving to Database correctly and im getting an error like **"Call to a member function getUsername() on null"**

From TokenInterface $token, i can print with $token->getUser(), it works correctly. I'm stuck really do not know where the problem is. I will give u some suspecious codes that maybe has error.

```
security.yaml
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            anonymous: ~
            pattern: ^/
            provider: steam_user_provider
            steam: true
            logout:
                path: /logout
                target: /
```

user.php

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->roles = [];
}

/**
 * @return array
 */
public function getRoles(): array
{
    $roles = [];
    foreach ($this->roles as $role) {
        $roles[] = new Role($role);
    }

    return $roles;
}
```

SteamProvider

```
class SteamProvider implements AuthenticationProviderInterface
{
/**
 * @var UserProviderInterface
 */
private $userProvider;

/**
 * @param UserProviderInterface $userProvider
 */
public function __construct(UserProviderInterface $userProvider)
{
    $this->userProvider = $userProvider;
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function authenticate(TokenInterface $token)
{
    $user = $this->userProvider->loadUserByUsername($token->getUsername());

    $authenticatedToken = new SteamUserToken();
    $authenticatedToken->setUser($user);
    $authenticatedToken->setUsername($user->getUsername());
    $authenticatedToken->setAuthenticated(true);

    return $authenticatedToken;
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function supports(TokenInterface $token)
{
    return $token instanceof SteamUserToken;
}
```

}

ContextListener. (Error shows up here)

```
  $token->setUser($refreshedUser);

            if (null !== $this->logger) {
                $context = ['provider' => \get_class($provider), 
'username' => $refreshedUser->getUsername()];

                foreach ($token->getRoles() as $role) {
                    if ($role instanceof SwitchUserRole) {
                        $context['impersonator_username'] = $role- 
>getSource()->getUsername();
                        break;
                    }
                }
```

I'm really sorry about this retarded question. But i do not have idea about why this error happening. Really $token->getUser() works perfectly, but in provider->refreshUser($token->getUser()) is giving NULL value.Maybe there is a error with roles but really do not know. If you need more examples about my code, just ask me. Thx for your helping

**Adding SteamUserProvider for more info**

```
/**
 * @var EntityManagerInterface
 */
private $entityManager;

/**
 * @var SteamApiClient
 */
private $api;

/**
 * @var string
 */
private $userClass;

/**
 * @var UserFactory
 */
private $userFactory;

/**
 * @param EntityManagerInterface $entityManager
 * @param SteamApiClient         $steamApiClient
 * @param string                 $userClass
 * @param UserFactory            $userFactory
 */
public function __construct(
    EntityManagerInterface $entityManager,
    SteamApiClient $steamApiClient,
    string $userClass,
    UserFactory $userFactory
)
{
    $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    $this->api = $steamApiClient;
    $this->userClass = $userClass;
    $this->userFactory = $userFactory;
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function loadUserByUsername($username)
{
    $user = $this->entityManager->getRepository($this->userClass)- 
>findOneBy(['steamId' => $username]);
    $userData = $this->api->loadProfile($username);
    if (null === $user) {
        $user = $this->userFactory->getFromSteamApiResponse($userData);

        $this->entityManager->persist($user);
    } else {
        $user->update($userData);
    }

    $this->entityManager->flush();

    return $user;
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function refreshUser(UserInterface $user)
{
    if (!$user instanceof SteamUserInterface) {
        throw new UnsupportedUserException();
    }

    return $this->entityManager->getRepository($this->userClass)- 
>findOneBy(['steamId' => $user->getSteamId()]);
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function supportsClass($class)
{
    return $class === $this->userClass;
}
```

Comment: Could you please show the UserProvider you are using (the one that has the `refresh($user)` method). It might also be useful to see, how the user from the steam authentication is saved to the database.

Comment: Hello i edited the question and added my user provider too

Comment: It looks like your `loadByUsername()` will always return a user, no matter what. Usually when a username (in your case the steam id) is not found, it should throw an exception. I don't think this is intended behavior. The same goes for `refreshUser()` at the very end you just return the result from the query and have no error handling in case the username does not exist. I am not sure how exactly your problem is caused, but not dealing with these cases might be related.

Comment: Most likely refreshUser returns null, because your `findOneBy()` returns null. Whether the user with the id does not exist or you have a session with an "invalid" user that does not have a steam Id, caused by the initial loadByUsername, I cannot say.

Comment: Thx for your advice i will check the output from there.

Comment: Yeah u was right, the functions works before saving user to Database, so in this case there was no user.  But i do not understand why this functions work first?